# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$refs' of undefined after router push vueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am working on a vue app and what my function does it to switch it to other page and load a dialog using $refs. However, I keep getting an error "Cannot read property '$refs' of undefined" . I know that when router switches pages, it goes to created hook and the refs are not loadded yet. How can I wait till refs are loaded? Below is my code! Thanks in advance!

```
openUpdateDetails(animalId) {
  this.$router
    .push(
      `/zoo/${
        this.$route.params.id
      }/animal/${animalId}/documents`
    )
    .finally(() => {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.$refs['panel'].$refs['animal-card'].handleAnimalDocument('change_animal');
        });
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should move that logic into the appropriate component's `mounted` hook?

Comment: @Phil the pages are on two separate files

Comment: Can you show the two templates (especially the refs)?

Comment: <AnimalPanel ref="panel" /> This is the component in the page I switched to after router.push. @tony19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a way to directly wait for the components to be mounted.
But I found other way to do.

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
next(vm => {
  setTimeout(() => {
      vm.$refs['panel'].$refs['animal-card'].handleNewAmendment('change_animal');
  }, 200);
});
```

I added this block before computed property of the page I am switching to. Hope this helps other people!